# How to Target multiple buttons with same class_Name such as 15 buttons in java_script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

my concern is there is a list and every list item has a button in front of them so i have to perform some action when user click on the button ,so how can i target the multiple buttons with same class_Name in java_script, Here is my j_s code =

```
function getActiveCampaigns() {
  fetch('http://example/api/sign/in', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      token: "token"
    }
  }).then(
    res => {
      res.json().then(
        data => {
          console.log(data.response.campaign, 'campaign');
          if (data.response.campaign.length > 0) {

            let temp = "";
            data.response.campaign.forEach((itemData) => {
              temp += "<ul>";
              temp += "<li>" + itemData.name + "</li>";
              temp += '<li><button class="btn1">Add to campaigns</button></li></ul>'
            });
            document.getElementById("ds").innerHTML = temp;
          }
        }
      )
    }
  )
}

 

   this code is that i have been tried but did not worked=
   

 
$("btn1").each(function click1(index, element) {
  var clas = $(element).attr("class");
  if(clas.length > 2) {
     // do something
     console.log("Hello World!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single click event listener can handle 1, 10, or 1,000 buttons with ease.

In my snippet, most of the code is concerned with creating and displaying 20 `li` elements, each with a button and some text.

A single click event listener handles clicks on any of the buttons. I've used an `AND` conditional to process the subset of events that occur on a `button` AND that are in a `li` of the correct class name (incase you have multiple lists and want to do different things on each. This is the event listener:

```
    document.addEventListener('click', event => {

      if (event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON' && event.target.parentElement.className == 'list-item') { 
       // stuff to execute
       alert(`${event.target.innerHTML} button pressed`);  
      } // end if;

    }); // end event listener;
```

Any number of `if` blocks could be added to the same event listener to deal with any other parts of the page for which you wish to process click events.

Note, no `ids` or anything complicated was needed to distinguish the target from others (that is the job of the lisener). This example didn't even need a class attribute but I included it so you can see how extra specificty can be achieved (e.g. you might have two lists with buttons and want to do different things with them).

Here is the working snippet:

```js
let list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {
let listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.setAttribute("class", "list-item");
listItem.innerHTML = `<button>element ${i}</button> list item ${i}`;
list.appendChild(listItem);
} // next.

document.addEventListener('click', event => {

  if (event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON' && event.target.parentElement.className == 'list-item') { 
   // stuff to execute
   alert(`${event.target.innerHTML} button pressed`);  
  }

});
```

```html
<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the support the whole code is not useful  for me but some part is , again thanks ....

Comment: You can target whatever number of buttons of whatever class (or any other distinguishing feature there is) by adapting it marginally. It is actually a universal solution for any click response. The `if` block can target whatever you like. Study it and you will see it most definitely can solve your problem and any others you have in future. I have used adaptions of this on thousands of pages it is universally adapatable one yo uunderstand it.

Comment: yeah sure, it really helped me a lot thanks man....

Comment: why my stackoverflow reputations not increasing i am asking some question for it

Answer (score 0):

```
const collection = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
```

getElementsByClassName method returns 'an array' ("a live HTMLCollection, which is very similar to an array" - user1599011) . You can iterate thru it like

```
foreach (element in array) {
Do anything with element}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a live `HTMLCollection`, which is very similar to an array, but not actually an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: You are absolutely right, i did not want to come up with these kind of special things, to keep my answer simple, but i modified my answer